# How Do I write multiple objects into Array using For Loop?

Tags: javascript

I have following codes:

```
for (lo = 0; lo < newobj.length; lo++) {
  lon = '{"lons":' + newobj[lo].longitude;
  lat = ',"lats":' + newobj[lo].latitude + '}';
  var string = '[' + lon + lat + ']';
  var obj = JSON.parse(string);
}
```

Thereafter, I do not know how to continue to get the expected outcome.

Example of data on the API. I actually just need the latitude and longitude to plot a billboard on cesium.

```
[

    {"description": "aaa", "address": "bbb", "latitude": "1.34791838898824", "longitude": "103.8487501254"},
    {"description": "ddd", "address": "ccc", "latitude": "1.37026158388488", "longitude": "103.839467898898"},
    ....
]
```

Expected outcome:

```
var dots=[{lon:103.84606,lat:1.3694},{lon:103.8447,lat:1.3697},…]
```

Comment: post your actual data.

Comment: can you post an example of your `newobj` array

Comment: Example of data on the API. I actually just need the latitude and longitude to plot a billboard on cesium.

[{"description":"aaa","address":"bbb","latitude":"1.34791838898824","longitude":"103.8487501254"},{"description":"ddd","address":"ccc","latitude":"1.37026158388488","longitude":"103.839467898898"},....]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting all in strings?

You can simply do it like this

```js
var dots = [];
for (lo = 0; lo < newobj.length; lo++) {
  dots.push({
    'lons': newobj[lo].longitude,
    'lats': newobj[lo].latitude
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Array.map : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
var newobj = [ {longitude : 103.84606 , latitude: 1.3694 }
             , {longitude : 103.8447 , latitude: 1.3697 }
             ]
         
var dots = newobj.map(elm=>({ lon: elm.longitude, lat: elm.latitude }) )

console.log( dots )
```

If you absolutely want a loop:

```js
var newobj = [ {longitude : 103.84606 , latitude: 1.3694 }
             , {longitude : 103.8447 , latitude: 1.3697 }
             ]
             
var dots = []
for (let elm of newobj) {
  dots.push({ lon: elm.longitude, lat: elm.latitude })
}

console.log( dots )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let dots= [];
for (lo = 0; lo < newobj.length; lo++) {
        lon= {
          "lons":newobj[lo].longitude,
        "lats":newobj[lo].latitude
};
dots.push(lon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var dots = [];
for (lo = 0; lo < newobj.length; lo++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.lon = newobj[lo].longitude;
    obj.lat = newobj[lo].latitude;
    dots.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObjArr = []

for (lo = 0; lo < newobj.length; lo++) {
    newObjArr.push([{lons: newobj[lo].longitude, lat: newobj[lo].latitude}])
}
```